# MOSFET Mobility

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

The surface mobility is lower than the bulk mobility because of surface roughness scattering

What is surface roughness scattering? How does it affect the mobility?

Answer (score 0):

It is scattering of the charge carriers by the roughness of the surface.

This lowers electron or hole mobility to below their bulk values.